# Strange onclick behavior after add style to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have html:

```
<div>
    <div id='icon_zoom_in' class='icon'>+</div>
    <div id='icon_zoom_out' class='icon'>-</div>
</div>
```

And I add CSS:

```
.icon{
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The result is nice (ignore the font, I installed a Chrome extension):

[image]

But when I add click event on their "buttons", strange things happen:

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
$("icon_zoom_in").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("zoom in");
}, false);
$("icon_zoom_out").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("zoom out");
}, false);
```

When I click the "+" button, I got `zoom out`! I have to click the outer space of it to get `zoom in`.
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wong2/w2dRB/

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? I just tried it in FF and it works good for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple: in Chrome the text is overflowing. Actually when you click the plus you are clicking the minus because of this. Use `overflow: hidden;` and the plus and minus will stick inside the buttons.
[Here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/w2dRB/3/) you can test the correct behaviour.

Comment: As far as I can see it's just some aesthetic glitch. Try forcing a `font-family`, If it doesn't work try with images or smaller `font-size` ;)